# Edit cell event getting cell value and position

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

In my Datagrid I allow users to edit some cells, after editing these cells I would like to commit the changes to the database (on enter). I am having troubles finding resources online to get this going.

I use an event called:

CellEditEnding but the event only provides me with the Row and Col how of the changed cell. How do I use these to find the cell itself and get the value?

Answer (score 4):

you could use this function found in this [link](http://techiethings.blogspot.com/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html)

```
public static DataGridCell GetCell(this DataGrid grid, DataGridRow row, int column)
{
    if (row != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);

        if (presenter == null)
        {
            grid.ScrollIntoView(row, grid.Columns[column]);
            presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
        }

        DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
        return cell;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and call it from your event handler :

```
object cellvalue = DataGridCell(yourgrid, e.Row, e.Column.DisplayIndex).GetValue;
```

this function is also called within the `GetCell()` function

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }
```

Comment: Error 1 The non-generic method 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetVisualChild(int)' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: and don't forget to include this namespace `using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;`