# Casting DataGrid row to DataGridCellPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to change the background of cell using some condition. I am using the `DataGrid.LoadingRow` event to achieve it. But I get an error when casting a row to `DataGridCellPresenter`. The error is

> The non-generic method 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetVisualChild(int)' cannot be used with type arguments".

Below is a screenshot of the error

[image: Please click to show Error Image]

Comment: To change the cell background color refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543187/setting-datagrid-cell-background-based-on-its-value-c-wpf/39543691#39543691). Also its better give your complete code

Comment: On your error... I usually cast with this format CastType variable = (CastType)function(...);

Comment: As per the error it seems like its not able to get the generic GetVisualChild<T> method. Did you defined the generic method? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388262/edit-cell-event-getting-cell-value-and-position)

Answer (score 0):

Changing cell background:

```
GetCell(dg, row, col).Background = Brushes.Yellow;

public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid dg, int row, int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(dg, row);
        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            if (presenter == null)
            {
                dg.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dg.Columns[column]);
                presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            }
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [AbZy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388349/6588087)'s code. If yes, you are probably left out another function definition called:
public static T GetVisualChild(Visual parent) where T : Visual

Besides GetVisualChild is a protected method in Visual Class. You can't call it as public.